# Upgrading a manually installed community extension via Magento Connect

Tags: magento-community, magento-connect, ee-1.12

Is this possible? I have Listrak_Remarketing already installed in an instance, but it does not show up under "Magento Existing Extensions" under System -> Magento Connect Manager. So, I'm assuming this was manually installed.

I tried upgrading this extension via Magento Connect, but it does not allow it because it's checking for existing files, and there are existing files.

Update 1: For reference, this is the error

```
Checking dependencies of packages

CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Listrak_Remarketing' is invalid
'./app/code/community/Listrak/Remarketing/Block/Adminhtml/Abandonedcartreport/Grid.php' already exists
```

Update 2: I found a site that lets you download the extension given the link obtained from Magento. Answer is below.

Update 3: Also, it looks like you may have a compressed extension file downloaded after all here even if it fails to install via Connect --> `downloader/.cache/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the files for the Magento Connect extension from [HERE](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php), it turns out, if you have the extension key from the Magento website.

Or possible from `magento_root/downloader/.cache/` as well.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't.  Magento Connect will refuse to install a package if any of the packages files already exist on the system.  While to you it seems like this extension is installed, since it was installed manually Magento Connect is unaware of it, and therefore can't upgrade it.  This is a (reasonable) precaution to ensure to package manager doesn't remove files on your system that may be coincidentally in the same place as another extension's files.

If you want to manage this extension via connect, you'll need to

- Look at the connect package to see which files (and directories) make up the extension, and remove any from your system
- Or, attempt to remove the files (and directories) one by one as the connect package manager finds them and complains
- Once that's done, install the package via connect

Backup your system before doing this and/or be ready for this to possibly fail in some weird, subtle way.

Comment: I downloaded and overwrote the files as in here(https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16344/14063) and moved the `package.xml` file in the root of the downloaded tar file to `/var/package/` and renamed the file to `[Namespace]_[Module]-[version].xml`. And Magento connect started showing the extension. At-least it seems like all the future updates can be done via Magento Connect

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take a new magento installation. 
Then install this module by Magento Connect on your new magento isntallation.

So then get this module manually and separate the files , so then put the new files on your store.

Remember to keep a backup from your files.

Comment: This is a neat trick, but instead of manually separating out the files, I'll see if a compressed file is in `var` exists, as oleksil has pointed out. I'll try it out..

Answer (score 1):

After first installation from connect, you will find the complete extension `Listrak_Remarketing` in `var` folder. Even if installation was not successful. Copy the code from extension directory and past into your magento root dir.

Or

Just delete all old files of this extension manually. And after try to install it.

Comment: I did get a `package.xml` in the `var` directory, but the extension files weren't actually there. This XML document has all of the files and directory structure, so I suppose Magneto Connect used this information to check and errored out before actually downloading files?

Comment: Even on a fresh installation, the complete extension is not available after the installation completes (it did get downloaded at one point according to the installation process output in Connect however).

Answer (score 1):

Yea, this can be a real pain.  What I do is manually download the package, then extract those files by hand.  It's really pretty simple.

This command says "go to magento connect and download the compressed files for the extension."

```
$ ./mage download [channel] [package name]
```

For example

```
$ ./mage download community m2epro_ebay_magento
```

This says, download the file, but don't install it.  You can tell what the package name is by the end of the URL from magento conntect URL.  the channel is just before it (community).
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento

You can find the file in downloader/.cache folder.  From there, you can either downlaod, extract, and manually upload the files or as I prefer, just untar them right from the server:

```
$ tar -xf archive.tar -C /target/directory
```

As a previous user wrote, you could use this website:
http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

But honestly, you have no idea if they manipulate or track that stuff before delivering.

Good luck.