# Can't Install any extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect-manager

i can't install any extension.
Magento Connctor 2.0 stops the Installing Process at
'Checking dependencies of packages' There isnt any other thing showing up.

I already checked the file permissions(setting everything to 777 wouldn't help).
I followed [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24120/unable-to-install-any-extension-using-magento-connect-manager-no-answer) and nothing Changed.
After Hours of googleing and testing I made a fresh Install and same Problem again.

**So i found the Failure.....
Someone Installed the domain for typo3 not magento...
Thanks everyone for your Help :)**

Comment: May be redundant, but have you disabled cache and compilation? see http://gotgroove.com/ecommerce-blog/magento-development/developer-toolbox-a-guide-for-installing-magento-extensions/ ; can you try to install your module manually?

Comment: @nicolallias Yes i disabled cache and compilation. i installed the modul manually without any problems.

Comment: What about manual install? Also, how many space is left on your server's disks? (on linux use command 'df -h')

Comment: @nicolallias Manual install works fine. Space is more then eneugh(50gb) :)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try to do a manual install:

1. Convert your magento connect 2.0 to a direct download:
   http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
2. Open your FTP client and upload the extension in your Magento folder

No files should be overwritten,

Flush magento cache and then log out and back into magento backend

Go to `configuration > advanced` to check if module is listed and enabled

Comment: I tested this and it works. But i hope that i find a way to get the connector working.

Comment: Use this Magento Cleanup to fix all permissions and try the connector again: https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php

upload this in your magento folder
SSH into your server
goto magento folder and type: php magento-cleanup.php

Comment: Done it. But same Problem again. Stops at 'Checking dependencies of packages'

Comment: Did a google for you seems to be related to php and gzip:


Go to downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Gz.php in your Magento directory
and replace

"$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);" 

with

"$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen64($this->_filePath, $mode);"

The alternative to doing this involves recompiling php

Comment: I tested this and it diddnt help. I started google at 9 this morning.... Something else I could do?